# resources mounted via sshfs and fstab on a nginx-server give 404 errors - gone on refresh

Tags: fstab, nginx, sshfs, fuse

Here is a scetch of the situation:
[image]

I'm running a `nginx` server (machine 2) which provides the work of our students. The student work itself lies on another machine (machine 1): our `gitolite` server.

In order to minimize `git clone`'s and data transfer (and for convenience), I'm mounting the student repositories (living on machine 1) as directories on the nginx server (machine 2) via `sshfs` and corresponding `fstab` entries.

This is one of the `fstab` entries on machine 2:

```
ssh-user@machine1.com:/path/to/student/work/on/machine1 /path/to/mount/point/on/machine2
   fuse.sshfs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,user,idmap=user,follow_symlinks,
   identityfile=/path/to/rsa-key/of/ssh-user/key_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,
   reconnect 0 0
```

(note: in the fstab file this is typeset as one single line, but for readability, I added newlines above)

This setup works in principle, meaning the works of the students are reachable via the website provided by nginx.

But when a user tries to look at the student work. Most of the time the user will receive a 404-error from nginx. This error can be fixed by simply reloading the page. But most users (obviously) won't do that (they simply assume the url is faulty).

I see two possible solutions:

1. (preferred:) fixing the 404 by some modification to the fstab entry, e.g. by fixing the cause of the 404 error
2. (if 1. failes:) configuring nginx in order to automatically reload (refresh) the page, if a 404 error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the `nginx` is running as a different user.
And by default `sshfs` mounts are only visible to the user that mounts them.

Therefore (by default) `nginx` can not see the files.

There are options for `sshfs`/`fuse` (`sshfs` is a `fuse` file-system). to make them more visible. (I can't remember, but it is in the manual).

Comment: I have no idea why it would work the 2nd time. Any you seem to have `allow_other`, in mount options.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But that's right: Sometimes it's working and sometimes it's not. Do you know, where I could search for the reason of the error?

Comment: I have no idea why it would work the 2nd time. I would edit the question, to focus on that point. Get the important bits at the top. Ask the question in as short paragraph. State what is not the problem. Then put the detail under this.